# Z-index caption is under div

Tags: z-index

i have got problem with this code :
[my code](http://jsbin.com/kocebucuje/1/edit?html,css,output)

The problem is here:

```
   .caption::before,
    .caption::after {
    z-index: -1;
    }

    #obsah {
        position:relative;
        background-color:red;
        //z-index: 0;
    }
```

(i think) .. I need the div#obsah under caption. 
Any idea to solve this problem? ;) I am novice. Thank you.

edit:

[IDEAL RESULT](http://jsfiddle.net/LsnxD/11/light/)

when you hover the image, it shows a text (cause image is move to right and overflow is hidden)
But my text is under the red background of div#obsah..

I remove overflow:hidden to see better where is problem. (but the codes are identical)

Comment: Could you please provide more details on what is the expected result? It's not very clear what you try to achieve. Maybe something like: when I do X, I want Y to happen, but I get Z.

Comment: edit, i hope it is better.

Comment: It works fine in the JS Fiddle that you provided. I hover my mouse cursor over the viking picture and the picture slides towards right so the writing stays visible. I don't see anything in red.

Comment: try here http://jsbin.com/kocebucuje/1/edit?html,css,output

Comment: You have different code in JS BIN vs JS Fiddle. Place the code from JS Bin in JS Fiddle and you will get the same error. You can see here: http://jsfiddle.net/ngb10y3s/

Comment: I took you good code from JS Fiddle and place it in JS Bin. Now JS Bin is fine too: http://jsbin.com/kowigipeju/1/edit?html,css,output

Comment: yes, but i need some "container" with red background under that picture. How to add it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally found a solution for this. You need to go to

```
#obsah {
      position:relative;
      display:block;
      padding-bottom:5px;
      margin-left:auto;
      margin-right:auto;
      margin-bottom:30px;
      background-color:red;
      width:75%;
  }
```

and do the following changes:

- change `position: relative;` to **`position: absolute;`**
- add **`z-index: -2;`**

Please see a working example here:

**[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tsb72wnz/)**